# Why does the `load` method of `DomDocument` show me errors like "Warning DOMDocument::load()" when I load French and Chinese Page?

Tags: php

**1 - With my code (French Wikipedia Page):**

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**I get the following error:**

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Specification mandates value for attribute checked in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 43 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 37 and span in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 68 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 37 and a in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 69 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: span line 37 and div in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 71 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: img line 37 and header in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 156 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: a line 37 and div in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 2971 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: header line 37 and body in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 2977 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: input line 37 and html in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 2978 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): EndTag: '</' not found in https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook, line: 2978 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 190
```

**2 - In the same way, with the following code (Japanese Wikipedia Page):**

```
$doc->load(rawurldecode("https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/亞馬遜公司"));
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

**Despite having used `rawurldecode` to no longer for the Asian language, I get the different following error:**

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Entity 'reg' not defined in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1382 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 181

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Entity 'trade' not defined in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1382 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 181
```

Why does the `load` method of `DomDocument` show me different errors when I use it with Pages in `French` (https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook) and in Asia (`Japanese` and `Chinese:` [https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/亞馬遜公司](https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA%9E%E9%A6%AC%E9%81%9C%E5%85%AC%E5%8F%B8)) **on the other hand works very well when the URL is in English ???**

Thank you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should use any get content method

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(file_get_contents("https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facebook"));
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 0):

And also when I try to use:

```
$doc->loadHTMLFile("https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/亞馬遜公司");
```

It seems to work as the result is displayed but just at the top of the result I get errors like this:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag wbr invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 77 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag wbr invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 77 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1140 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1158 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1175 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1202 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1219 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1277 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1294 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1310 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1326 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1342 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag nav invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1359 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210

Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTMLFile(): Tag footer invalid in https://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E4%BA...85%AC%E5%8F%B8, line: 1378 in C:\laragon\www\test.php on line 210
```

I really need your help. Please.

Comment: $dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML('...');
libxml_clear_errors();

Comment: libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

Comment: U can use libxml_use_internal_errors(true);

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all. I was able to solve this by simply adding: `libxml_use_internal_errors(true);`

Comment: Sign as solved my answer...